# Not able to install Apps via Ubuntu Software Center or Terminal

Tags: apt, software-installation, downloads

I was trying to install Dropbox. Didn't worked out thou:

```
sudo apt-get install Dropbox
E: Konnte keinen exklusiven Zugang zur Sperrdatei /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend erhalten. Diese wird vom Prozess 10625 (apt) gehalten.
N: Beachten Sie, dass das Entfernen der Sperrdatei keine Lösung ist und Ihr System zerstören kann.
E: Konnte die dpkg Oberflächen-Sperre (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend) nicht erlangen, benutzt evtl. ein anderer Prozess diese gerade?
```

Comment: This is probably a temporary problem. As the error text say's, apt is running and keeping the lock. This happens when apt is checking for updates (`apt -update`) is running in the background. Wait a few minutes ad try again.

Comment: Dropbox doesn't appear to be in the repos, at least for 20.04 and 18.04. Download the appropriate .deb from: https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux

Comment: I installed Dropbox on 20.04 only the other day from Ubuntu Software Centre using Server for France. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In English, the logs would be -

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 10625 (apt)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

This indicates that another process (apt) was running at that time probably in another terminal or perhaps spawned by the gnome software.

Now, only one instance of apt is allowed to run on a machine to prevent race conditions where both processes simultaneously try to install a software and may cause undesired effects.

Just close the other process and try again.

PS : as mentioned in a comment dropbox is not available in the standard repositories.
You should download the deb file from the website itself-
https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux